# How can I update an on-screen countdown exactly when the system clock ticks on Android

Tags: java, android, countdown, clock

I am making a countdown in Android, and while I did get the countdown mostly working, I have one problem.

Here's my current code:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Date now = new Date();
    long timeUntilLaunch = launch.getNet().getTime() - now.getTime();
    countdownView.setText(countdownFormat.format(new Date(timeUntilLaunch)));

    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
  }
}, 1000);
```

And this works, but the main problem I am facing right now is that this will update once per second, starting from the time this part of the code executes, which means that the countdown could be up to 1 second off. That is because if this runs 900ms after the seconds tick, the countdown would wait until x.9 seconds before refreshing.

My first approach to solving this was using an empty while loop that waits until the the seconds tick, then lets this run, but I quickly found out that that is a terrible idea since it freezes the whole app.

What would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: Android has a class called CountDownTimer, check it out here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Comment: I did this, but it seems that the behavior is exactly the same, so the countdown doesn't update right at the moment the seconds of the system clock update

Comment: @YonatanAvhar can I kindly ask why is it that you want this to update exactly at the moment the seconds of the system clock update?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified this.
I have multiple views inside of a RecyclerView, and while scrolling, the task that is done by the handler gets called whenever the user scrolls, meaning that the 6 or so timers on screen don't update all at once, which looks quite bad (and it also annoys my "ocd").

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. Instead of always firing the Handler with 1000ms delay, I am giving it a delay of `1000 - (now.getTime() % 1000)`, which means it will always wait until the second ticks over to update again. Here's my completed code:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Date now = new Date();
    long timeUntilLaunch = launch.getNet().getTime() - now.getTime();
    countdownView.setText(countdownFormat.format(new Date(timeUntilLaunch + 1000)));

    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 - (now.getTime() % 1000));
  }
}, 0);
```